# Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: ... Access is denied

Tags: go-ethereum

What should you do if you get an error similar to the below when starting geth?

> Fatal: Error starting protocol stack:  Access is
>   denied.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This occurs when you have another instance of geth already running.

Use your Operating System's process handler to end the process if there are no visible windows.

This happened to me when I started (and then closed) mist before I had set a private network running.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04: I don't have another instance of Geth already running, but I get this error.

Answer (score 5):

You can have multiple instances of Geth on different ports using the **--port** flag, and to solve the error message above, just run all Geth instances with the **--ipcdisable** flag.

Note: **ipcdisable** is going to disable IPC communication, which is not required if you are using JSON RPC.

Comment: This didn't work for me, unfortunately.