# Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: resource temporarily avalible (Virtual Machine Ubuntu)

Tags: go-ethereum, mining

This happened as soon as I typed in

> geth

This also happened when I typed in

> geth --rpc --fast --cache=2048

Does anybody have a fix? Keep in mind I run on virtualbox.

Comment: All I had to do was kill the process. I then reopened it and it's now working.

Answer (score 1):

This will have happened because you already had an instance of Geth running.

This sort of error can happen when you try to start a second instance of Geth, and it can't grab the resources it needs because the first instance has them. When you killed Geth, you were killing the original instance.

Similar issues have come up before, though with slightly different errors. See [Fatal: Error starting protocol stack: ... Access is denied](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10616/fatal-error-starting-protocol-stack-access-is-denied)